# mysqldump just isn't working

Tags: java, mysql

I've been looking at this for a little bit now.

I have run this exact command from the command line and I know it works:

```
mysqldump --user=user --password=password db > C:\\db.sql
```

However, in Java, it just skips right over and says the backup failed. What am I missing?:

```
        Process exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mysqldump --user=user --password=password db > C:\\db.sql");

        int processComplete = exec.waitFor();

        if(processComplete == 0)
            log.info("Backup successful.");
        else
            log.info("Backup failed. STOP GETTING HERE :(");
```

Any ideas? I have looked at other questions here, including using a ProcessBuilder, but nothing has worked.

**Edit**

Tried this:

exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqldump.exe --user=user --password=password db > C:\db.sql");

No luck either.

I've always tried / instead of \ and did not have luck. I've restarted MySQL and checked permissions too.

Comment: What's the working directory in the command line and what's the working directory when you try to execute the command from java?

Comment: Working directory with the cmd is the C: and the command from java is literally what you see.

Comment: Also - Why am I getting requests to close and downvoted? At least explain it...

Comment: My guess is that the java call does not find the mysqldump executable. I would provide its full path, hence my question around the working directory.

Comment: Could it be escaping of the backslashes?

Comment: Will add C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\ to the process and try again.

Comment: What is the exit code? Probably the redirect to a file does not work, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.Redirect.html#to(java.io.File)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue appears to be related to how I was using mysqldump in my code. When I rewrote the command to this:

```
Process exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mysqldump -u user -ppassword db -r C:\\db.sql");
```

It worked.

Just incase anyone wants the solution in the future.